# Multiple condition on dom events

Tags: javascript

I have need to do two things on a single DOM event

I tried using this but it won't work.

HTML

```
<input type="test" name="box" id="box" onkeyup="keyPressedBox(this)">
<input type="test" name="name" id="name" onkeyup="keyPressedName(this)">

<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" checked="checked" id="sdp_1" name="sdp_1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" checked="checked" id="sdp_2" name="sdp_2"/>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
     function keyPressedName(str) {
        if ($(str).val() != '') {
            $('#sdp_2').prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $('#sdp_2').prop('checked', true);
        }

        return true;
    }

    function keyPressedBox(str) {
        if ($(str).val() != '') {
            $('#sdp_1').prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $('#sdp_1').prop('checked', true);
        }
        return true;
    }


</script>
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Dont' try to jam everything in an inline handler for starters.  Looks like you have some other tenuous stuff going on.  Move that out into a named function which you can then attach and then also explain what those `#` prefixed variables are.  Format that block and I'm guessing also correct the syntax so it makes sense.

Comment: The string `'#box'` has no property `value`. What do expect *#box* to be?

Comment: Change your `$('#name').val() !== ''` to `$('#name').val() != ''`

Comment: change `onkeypress` to `onkeyup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this

```
onkeypress="keyPressed();"
```

And `keyPressed`. Have 2 functions in both `input` box. functions will be,

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
        function keyPressedName(str) {
            if ($(str).val() != '') {
                $('#sdp_2').prop('checked', false);
            } else {
                $('#sdp_2').prop('checked', true);
            }

            return true;
        }

        function keyPressedBox(str) {
            if ($(str).val() != '') {
                $('#sdp_1').prop('checked', false);
            } else {
                $('#sdp_1').prop('checked', true);
            }
            return true;
        }

    </script>
```

HTML will be

```
<input type="test" name="box" id="box" onkeyup="keyPressedBox(this)">

<input type="test" name="name" id="name" onkeyup="keyPressedName(this)">
```

JS FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/RMEKh/2/

Comment: I have edited, can you try now ? .. tell me what `'#box'.value`. You must have to edit that

Comment: '#box'.value is value for my texbox. what i want to do  is

When the user type on the texbox, i want the checkbox to be uncheck automatically

Comment: nope..

This code worked though
 `function keyPressed ()
{
    if ( '#box'.value !='' ) {
        document.getElementById('sdp_1').checked = false;
    } 
    if ( '#name'.value !='' ) {
        document.getElementById('sdp_2').checked = false;
    }

    return true;
}`


but it run both situation...

Comment: Change your `$('#name').val() !== ''` to `$('#name').val() != ''`

Comment: I have edited, it works. pass `keyPressedName(this)` like that

Comment: change `onkeypress` to `onkeyup`

Comment: i've updated my codes  in the question. Is there anything that is still wrong. It still wont' work.

Comment: change `onkeypress` to `onkeyup`

Comment: Think you are not loading Jquery.